# Elasticsearch - Sort By Distance Not Working?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I have an index where the records are stored in the following format:

```
"_source": {
  "name": "ACME Pallets",
  "about": null,
  "slug": "acme-pallets",
  "serviceAreas": [
      {
          "admin1": "usa",
          "admin2": null,
          "admin3": null,
          "admin4": null,
          "countryCode": "US",
          "googlePlaceId": null,
          "locality": null,
          "selectedLevel": "admin1"
      }
  ],
  "id": "fadsflsjdfkk3234234",
  "addresses": [
      {
          "address1": "4342 Dietrich Rd",
          "address2": null,
          "city": "San Antonio",
          "countryCode": "US",
          "latitude": 29.44122,
          "longitude": -98.34404,
          "primary": true,
          "name": "office",
          "postal": "78219",
          "province": "TX",
          "location": {
              "lat": 29.44156,
              "lon": -98.37704
          }
      }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to return results from this index where the records are sorted by distance to the search point I pass in.  My sort config being passed in looks like this:

```
_geo_distance: {
  'addresses.location': { lat: 31.75917, lon: -106.48749 },
  order: 'asc',
  unit: 'mi',
  mode: 'min'
}
```

The results I receive back are not sorted according to distance.  If I manually plot out the individual locations on a map and the search pin passed in, I can see that the sorting is out of order.

If I pass in a sorting config to my search to sort by alphabetically order or to sort by relevance (aka `_score`), the sorting returned is correct.

Does anyone know why ES might be returning my results incorrectly when sorting by distance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`addresses` is an array in my index.  Each object inside of `addresses` has a property called `location` of type **geo_point**.

From all the documentation that I've read, passing `'addresses.location': { lat: 31.75917, lon: -106.48749 }` into the search should work, but it doesn't.  ES should be smart enough to find the location geo point in each object and use that as the reference when calculating the distance.  If there are more than one object inside of the `addresses` array, then ES by default should get the center point of all the objects inside of `addresses` and use that to calculate the distance from the search point.

In my case, I don't have any data where `addresses` has more than one object.  I ended up creating a `location` **geo_point** property outside of the `addresses` property during index build and then passing in  `location: { lat: 31.75917, lon: -106.48749 }` for the search.  This made ES sort results based on distance correctly.

What my new index looks like with the added `location` property:

```
"_source": {
  "name": "ACME Pallets",
  "about": null,
  "slug": "acme-pallets",
  "serviceAreas": [
      {
          "admin1": "usa",
          "admin2": null,
          "admin3": null,
          "admin4": null,
          "countryCode": "US",
          "googlePlaceId": null,
          "locality": null,
          "selectedLevel": "admin1"
      }
  ],
  "id": "fadsflsjdfkk3234234",
  "addresses": [
      {
          "address1": "4342 Dietrich Rd",
          "address2": null,
          "city": "San Antonio",
          "countryCode": "US",
          "latitude": 29.44122,
          "longitude": -98.34404,
          "primary": true,
          "name": "office",
          "postal": "78219",
          "province": "TX",
          "location": {
              "lat": 29.44156,
              "lon": -98.37704
          }
      }
  ]
  "location": {
      "lat": 29.44156,
      "lon": -98.37704
  }
}
```